# Replay tplog in kdbb

Tags: kdb

I tried to replay tplog in kdb. The data is about 1gb, but it takes the whole day and still cannot finish replaying.

One of the tables has two keys and both are `string`. I am not sure if this is the reason why it takes forever. I also use `upsert` instead of `insert`. What should I change to make it replay faster?

What I think is to change `upd` function. so when load to memory, those two columns change to `symbol` first.

Comment: I assume you're using a keyed tables and upserting in order to have a unique row per key(s). Why not start with an unkeyed table and set upd to insert and when the replay is complete then group the table based on the keys (possibly using `fby`)

Comment: @terrylynch thanks! that works. I just have a question, if i changed to insert but I didn't unkey the table. it didn't work. it has some insert error, but there is no duplicated keys though. Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah the 'insert error is due to an "Attempt to insert a record with an existing key into a keyed table", as per https://code.kx.com/q/ref/error-list/

Comment: @terrylynch, please copy your comment above as the answer so that people can take advantage of your suggestion/solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, if the purpose for using a keyed table with upserting was to have a unique row per key(s) then it may be more efficient (when it comes to log replay) to start with an unkeyed table and set upd to `insert` and when the replay is complete then group the table based on the keys, for example

```
`keyCol1`keyCol2 xkey select from replayedTable where i=(last;i) fby ([]keyCol1;keyCol2)
```

Note that `insert` cannot be used with a keyed table as it does not allow an insert when the key already exists in the table.

The reason the original `upsert` on the keyed table was slow was possibly due to the number of keys and the inefficiency of looking up the key list (specifically of strings) on each upsert. This is just speculation though